# What is the best way to cache a P2 target in a Gitlab CI Tycho build?

Tags: gitlab-ci, tycho, p2

I have an existing Tycho project, which uses [Eclipse Target Defintions](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Tycho/Packaging_Types#eclipse-target-definition) to resolve the target platform. The download is slow, so I would like to implicitly cache this, if possible. I have the [Gitlab CI cache](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/yaml/README.html#cache) mechanism available. However, I do not know what the most elegant way would be to cache the target locally.

Note: The Gitlab CI cache is *not* reliable. It can disappear or not be present at all on some builds.

Comment: Tycho caches p2 downloads in the local maven repository

Comment: Does that mean that it will not access P2 indexes either? These also cause turn-arounds.

Comment: yes. the only thing left are HTTP HEAD requests to check if anything changed remotely in comparison to the local cache. You can suppress even this using mvn --offline